# How to link a html form's inputs to remote SQL database using NodeJS, not PHP?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I have the following html form:

```
<form id="shipnow-form" class="form-signin"  action="" method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm(event)"> 
      <ul id="progressbar">
        <li>Your Personal Details</li>
        <li>Thank You</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <div class="text-center mb-4">
      </div>

      <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="Name" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
      </div>

      
      <br>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color:#d40511; border-style:hidden;" type="submit" ><b>Proceed</b></button>
    </form>
```

I have been given the following codes to connect to the SQL database:

```
//Create connection
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "abcd.mysql.database.azure.com",
    user: "abcd@seft",
    password: "asdfghjk",
    database: "salesoffer",
    port: "3306",
});
```

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO sales(name, email) VALUES('${name}', '${email}')";
```

I have tried using NodeJS and ran the following code:
**app.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


//Create connection
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "abcd.mysql.database.azure.com",
    user: "abcd@seft",
    password: "asdfghjk",
    database: "salesoffer",
    port: "3306",
});

//connect to mysql
conn.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("MYSQL Connected");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO sales(name, email) VALUES('${name}', '${email}')";

});
```

I am trying to connect the html form to the SQL database. This assignment is part of my internship, so I am sourcing for quick solutions from anyone who is expert in this. The SQL database has already been created by the company, and I am provided with 2 code snippets, and asked to connect the html form inputs to the database. For the company's protection, I have replaced the database connection code hostname and other details.

I have seen many solutions involving the use of PHP language, but the 2 code snippets don't seem to be of PHP language, and seems more like NodeJS javascript.

When I run **app.js**, it returns an error:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Client with IP address '49.245.120.139' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dhlmacbookpro/Downloads/ShipNow/database.js:14:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT',
  errno: 9000,
  sqlMessage: "Client with IP address '49.245.120.139' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.",
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  fatal: true
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track by using NodeJS, since customers don't use terminals when they browse a website.

Also, I am not sure if its a database error that it should have allowed my computer to connect to it, or if it is because I am using the wrong approach to connect to the database.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about asking for clarification from your co-workers or manager if you don't know how to approach this. We don't know _exactly_ what they are expecting of you, and we also can't help with your database connection issue which clearly suggests that you're not allowed to connect to the database from the IP-address that you're running the code from.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if I am on the right track by using NodeJS, since customers don't use terminals when they browse a website.

They use web browsers, which communicate using HTTP. Your Node.js program needs to communicate with the browser over HTTP and not directly with the end user (using a terminal).

You need to use Node.js to write a web service for the browser to communicate with. [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) provides a popular framework for doing this.

> Client with IP address '49.245.120.139' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

You also need to run the Node.js program that provides said web service on a computer which is allowed to connect to the database.

> I have seen many solutions involving the use of PHP language, but the 2 code snippets don't seem to be of PHP language, and seems more like NodeJS javascript.

Server-side code can be written in **any** programming language. JavaScript (via Node.js) and PHP are two of the more popular ones.